# Why are we not able to give input to the string s1 in the following code?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;
public class MovieInfo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the film");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the film budget");
    int bud = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the running time");
    double time = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the film production house");
    String s1 = in.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Film being screened : "+name);
    System.out.println("Budget "+bud+" cores");
    System.out.println("Running time "+time+" hours");
    System.out.println("Production : "+s1);
}
}
```

In the output of the above program, it does not take input for String s1.
How do I fix it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? what is your input? what does your print statement print?

Comment: Run the above program in your system. We are able to give input to String name, int bud, double time but when it comes to next line it just prints "Enter the film production house" and terminates the program. It is not taking any input to String s1. @Stultuske

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the following additional line:

```
in.nextLine();
```

after that line:

```
double time = in.nextDouble();
```

to consume **new line character** (it's created when you accept input `double` with **Enter** key) that is not being consumed with `.nextDouble()` call.

---

Please refer to link to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/8116173), provided by **LenosV**, to get detailed information on what's the reason of that behavior of `Scanner`.

Comment: Adding a reference for more details to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: @LenosV Thank you, I was on my was to add further explanations, but your link seems to cover it all very well.

Comment: Thanks guys..! That fixed my problem.

Comment: @shreyas Glad that I could help. You might want to consider accepting answer that solved your problem and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
import java.util.*;
public class MovieInfo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the film");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the film budget");
    int bud = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the running time");
    double time = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the film production house");
    String s1 = in.next(); 
    System.out.println("Film being screened : "+name);
    System.out.println("Budget "+bud+" cores");
    System.out.println("Running time "+time+" hours");
    System.out.println("Production : "+s1);
}
}
```

Comment: This code will work, but in String s1 next() method will read only one word not an entire line.